# Do I have any hope to recover my blogspot-bound account?

Tags: support, accounts

all. I use to have a SO account with only OpenID log-in linked to my blogspot website. Unfortunately, google seems that have broken something with OpenID which they just can't fix. Afaik, no e-mail address was set for that "lost" account. Is there any way I can recover my former account ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) with as much information about your old profile as you can and we'll see what we can do.